# Needing help on Excel Text function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I am trying to use the Text function to format a number in the middle of a string for a cell.

Basically the formula is this

```
="Total Sales: "&Text(B2,"$0,000")
```

Now my results look strange if the value of B2 gets low.

Like 150 would return $0,150

I'm sure I am overlooking something obvious.  Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

="Total Sales: "&TEXT(B2,"$#,000")

the # means, essentally, 'Only if needed.'

Comment: Thank you. That does exactly what I was looking for.  I didn't know about the #.